# I cannot get decimal after doing a simple division math

Tags: iphone, decimal, division

Look at my simple math script

```
double s = 3/2;
NSLog (@"%.2f",s);
```

I get 1, it should be 1.50

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double s = 3/2` means divide the int 3 by the int 2, and then cast the result (which is the int 1) to a double (giving you 1.0).

You want this:

```
double s = 3.0/2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `double s = 3/2.0`
both 3 and 2 are integers, so despite receiver being double, you still get an int result and it is then converted to double

Answer (score 0):

3 and 2 are integers. So 3/2 is 1. You should try instead

```
double s = 3.0/2.0;
NSLog (@"%1.2f",s);
```

It will give you the right answer.